# What is a more efficient solution for this linear algebra problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[image]

In the above question , one way of approach is definitely multiplying the matrices and comparing the respective elements then solving the equations. But I am not able to figure out a more efficient solution?

Comment: Please write an *INFORMATIVE* title.  Yours is so vague it could apply to innumerable questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix equation can be written as $\vec{c} \times \vec{b} = \vec{a} - \vec{c}$, using the cross product.

The left-hand side is orthogonal to $\vec{b}$ (property of cross products), and $\vec{a}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{b}$, so dotting the equation with $\vec{b}$ says that $0 = \vec{b} \cdot \vec{c}$. So (B) is true.

Rewriting our equation as $\vec{c} + (\vec{c} \times \vec{b})= \vec{a}$ gives a decomposition of $\vec{a}$ as a sum of two orthogonal vectors. By the Pythagorean theorem then, $\lVert\vec{c}\rVert^2 + \lVert \vec{c} \times \vec{b}\rVert^2 = \lVert \vec a\rVert^2 = 11$, so $\lVert\vec{c}\rVert^2 \leq 11$ and so $\lVert\vec{c}\rVert \leq \sqrt{11}$. So (D) is true.

If $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{c} = 0$, then dotting both sides of the equation with $\vec{c}$ then gives that $\lVert\vec{c}\rVert^2=0$, so $\vec{c}=0$, but then $\vec{0} = \vec{c}\times \vec{b} = \vec{a} - \vec{c} = \vec{a}$, which is false because $\vec{a}\neq 0$. So (A) is false.

The condition $\vec a \cdot \vec b = 0$ expands to $3 + b_2 - b_3 = 0$, so $|b_3 - b_2| = 3$, and since $b_2b_3 > 0$, we must have one of these numbers have absolute value larger than $3$. But then $b_2^2 + b_3^2 > 9$, so $\lVert \vec b \rVert=\sqrt{1 + b_2^2 + b_3^2} > \sqrt{10}$, and so (C) is true.

Comment: You mean (C) is true for the last one? The original statement is whether the norm of $b$ is greater than $\sqrt{10}$

Comment: Edited, thanks.